# Magento 2 Checkout Validation doesn't work

Tags: magento2, checkout, form-validation

I've created a module which extends the **magento 2 checkout**, where I've added another field according with the magento documentation:
`http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html`

This has worked and they are displayed on the frontend, however the validation causes a weird error.
If I use:

`<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
 </item>`

As per the documentation, the field shows an asterisk (showing this is a required field), however upon submitting the form the error doesn't display and it doesn't prevent the form submitting.

Comment: have you recompile?

Comment: setup:di:compile ?

Comment: yes,  bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I've re-run it and it's had no affect

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery questions.</item>
      </item>
   </item>
   <!-- add a validation code at here -->
   <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="string">true</item>
   </item>
   <!-- end of validation -->
</item>
```

you can also refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118010/magento-2-how-to-add-extra-validation-to-check-out-address-form/118034) url.

if not work let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
This actually doesn't produce anything at all in my module.
Just to confirm it wasn't caching, I reverted back to my previous xml and that displayed.

Comment: ohhh..
take care next time.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand - my previous xml still fails to validate but it does display a field. Yours doesn't display a field.