# How to Update/Override Core form Validation in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to override or update core validation for magento frontend form like as checkout page form address field validation change.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8nw2.png]

need to change the core validation

Answer (score 0):

You must use this:

1) In input or select tag add our validaion with this code

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-custom-name':true}"
```

2) Add js validation for “Validate-custom-name”

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', // jquery Library
    'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
    'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
    'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('validate-custom-name', function(value) {
        return (value !== 'test'); // Validation logic here
    }, $.mage.__('Enter Valid name'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: I need to core validation change. like as phone no validation change..please see update image. please share full answer..thanx a lot.

Comment: yeah, exactly! you want to change the validation message, like on phone number field, you want to show **Phone number is required**, then you can use the above mentioned method only..

Comment: which file in change?? i need in my custom module.

Comment: use first code in the file where the element tag is. and use second code wherever you can run a jQuery code (like phtml etc.) but it is highly recommended to use a js file.

Comment: I know this work for custom form..can you share full code?? http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-add-new-custom-form-validation/

Comment: hey @manish can you suggest how to change core validation for shipping form?

Comment: I think, you can use http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118010/magento-2-how-to-add-extra-validation-to-check-out-address-form